# Why are centrifuge space-station designs not a reality?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force, space-travel

Considering how [useful it could be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_gravity) for the crew of a space station to have at their disposal a 1g environment (or more) at the rim to a 0g environment at the axis of rotation, why aren't modern space stations like the [ISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Space_Station) built around a centrifuge design à la [Interstellar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film))? And if they already exist, why haven't I heard of them?

[image]

Comment: Would [space.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: The question is not a duplicate, but the accepted answer does provide most of the engineering detail that I am looking for as to why centrifuge designs (especially small ones like the one pictured above) are not viable.

Comment: I would urge this question not to be closed, as there may be other explanations beyond the single answer in the linked post...

Comment: Have you worked out how big one of these things ought to be to insure against excessive motion sickness (no one knows for sure so the answers you'll find vary; I figure 30-100 meters radius of rotation). Have you compared the mass of such a critter to that of the largest space station ever build (ISS)? Do you know what it costs to lift a kilogram to medium Earth orbit?